# LD_PRELOAD has no visible effect

Tags: ubuntu, elf, inject, ld-preload

I have my .so library which i inject into various processes on my Ubuntu server. But i found binary file which i start with regular command:

> LD_PRELOAD=/home/glinkd/preload32.so ./glinkd 1

And nothing happens! No errors, no my preload logs, nothing, but glinkd runs ok.
My preload binary is 32bit, glinkd is 32bit, Ubuntu is 64bit. I tested with another 32bin binaries and all works well, problem is only with glinkd.

What could it be?

Comment: What does `ls -l ./glinkd` show?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it shows "-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2884295 aug.   1 17:01 ./glinkd"

Answer (score 0):

Since `glinkd` is statically linked, trying to hook the executable's invocation of dynamically-linked functions will not work since there are no such functions to hook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but   LD_SHOW_AUXV=1 ./glinkd 1 
 gives nothing too. I think there is another reason

Comment: No, glinkd runs as always, but there is no table with AT_SYSINFO_EHDR,AT_HWCAP and etc.

Comment: I think glinkd avoid all LD* somehow

Comment: If i try `LD_SHOW_AUXV=1 ping` or `LD_SHOW_AUXV=1 sleep` or another binary all is ok, table exists

Comment: I've just test on another server with same system, all is ok with `LD_SHOW_AUXV=1 ping`. Just Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I tried `strace` on `glinkd` and if i use LD_PRELOAD, glinkd even doesn't try to open .so file, on another binary all is ok, i see: `open("./preload32.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3`

Comment: Preload entry point defined as: `void active_ld_const(void) __attribute__((constructor));`

Comment: glinkd doesn't load environment variables, that's why LD sommands doesn't work. Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: @Kracken I can't tell what's going on without experimenting and replicating. What is `glinkd`?

Comment: it is binary file of PerfectWorld server. Link to file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5d99gq6bjovkxf/glinkd?dl=0 . You could try to start it with some LD command and it will not work. `LD_PRELOAD` or `LD_SHOW_AUXV` for example. I can't understand why this file avoid environment variables

Comment: It will fall with error `Usage: ./glinkd configurefile section_num` because you don't have config file but this error happens already in main function, after LD_PRELOAD must take action

Comment: It's statically linked!

Comment: it is no possible to LD_PRELOAD or use some LD commands to static linked binary? I'm not hooking functions

Comment: What else can you do exactly? It's quite possible there's a way to do whatever it is you're trying to do, but I'd have to know what it is that you're trying to do. Usually, you use `LD_PRELOAD` to hook or replace dynamically linked library functions.

Comment: Sorry, i was mistaken, yes, i'm hooking functions. I'm hooking socket functions like send recv and etc. to encrypt all traffic on specified port without modifying binary. It is fast, maybe there is another way to do this?

Comment: And it is also possible to hook system call table? even if glinkd was compiled statically

Comment: I think it is possible to make my preload work with glink by forcing somehow loading my preload and hook system calls instead of dynamically-linked functions. But how to force static linked binary to load my preload?

Comment: @Kracken It's not easy. You can punch "linux system call hook" into your favorite search engine.